# Iterating and for function - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I can't seem to get my head around this. I would appreciate some help. It looks to me like the for function is iterating at a rate of n+1 for every new iteration, although I can't figure out why.

Here is my Python code:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    print "This is %d" % n
    for x in range(2, n):
        print "%d" % n
```

And here is the output in Powershell:

```
This is 2
This is 3
3
This is 4
4
4
This is 5
5
5
5
This is 6
6
6
6
6
This is 7
7
7
7
7
7
This is 8
8
8
8
8
8
8
This is 9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: range accepts three arguments. range(start, stop, step).
u are passing start and stop. so its printing what it should be

Comment: @Raz debug code and see how it works step by step. You will get much more information.

Comment: I don't have a debugger. What is that?

Comment: @Raz debuger is an utility which allows you to run your code line-by-line. And on each step you can see what variables contain. Google it.

Comment: I will. cheers Alexander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        ...
```

You have *nested* loops. The upper bound of the inner loop is set to the *current* value of the *outer* loop.

The outer loop will iterate from 2 (incl.) to 10 (excl.):

1. At first iteration, `n` is `2`. So, the inner loop will iterate from 2 (incl.) to 2 (excl.). As the upper bound is in fact equal to the lower bound, the inner loop does not iterate.
2. At second iteration of the outer loop, `n` is `3`. So, the inner loop will iterate from 2 (incl.) to 3 (excl.). So there is *one* iteration of the *inner* loop with `x = 2`
3. At third iteration of the outer loop, `n` is `4`. So, the inner loop will iterate from 2 (incl.) to 4 (excl.). There is two iterations of the inner loop (`x = 2` and the `x = 3`).

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

The end value for a range is *not included*, so the range from `2` to `2` doesn't include any values. You then create a range from `2` to `3`, which only includes the value `2`, etc.

As such, you are producing loops that'll loop `n - 2` times, where `n` loops from 2 to 9 inclusive, and each inner loop loops from 2 to `n - 1`, inclusive.

For each nested loop, you are printing `n` again, which doesn't change in the inner loop. Try printing `x` instead, or better still, print it *together*:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    print "This is %d" % n
    for x in range(2, n):
        print "n=%d, x=%d" % (n, x)
```

For each `n` this'll print the values for `x` from 2 to `n - 1`, inclusive:

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     print "This is %d" % n
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         print "n=%d, x=%d" % (n, x)
... 
This is 2
This is 3
n=3, x=2
This is 4
n=4, x=2
n=4, x=3
This is 5
n=5, x=2
n=5, x=3
n=5, x=4
This is 6
n=6, x=2
n=6, x=3
n=6, x=4
n=6, x=5
This is 7
n=7, x=2
n=7, x=3
n=7, x=4
n=7, x=5
n=7, x=6
This is 8
n=8, x=2
n=8, x=3
n=8, x=4
n=8, x=5
n=8, x=6
n=8, x=7
This is 9
n=9, x=2
n=9, x=3
n=9, x=4
n=9, x=5
n=9, x=6
n=9, x=7
n=9, x=8
```

Comment: But why is 4 printed twice, and 5 three times, and 6 four times, etc?

Comment: Why is it looping n - 2 times?

Comment: `4` is printed twice because you coded it. You have an inner loop `for x in range(2, n):` and if n is `4` it loops over the values `2` and `3`. Did you want to print `x` instead?

Comment: @Raz: you are simply printing `n`. Did you mean to print `x` instead?

Comment: Martin I posted another answer to this addressed to you - I can't seem to fit it all in to this comments thread but if you scroll down you will see it.

Comment: @Raz: only use answer posts for actual answers; perhaps you can join us in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) for follow-up questions instead. I'm not available 24-7 but the chatroom *is* and is populated by other knowledgeable Python developers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now. Within every single iteration of the first for loop, the second foor loop will iterate once for every 'x' value between 2 and n.

So if n is 7, the first for loop will iterate once for the number 7, and the second for loop will iterate once for every value between 2 and 7 (i.e. 5 times).